# how to get hibernate search score for each object in query result list

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

Here is my code

```
    luceneQuery = qb.bool()
                .should(qb.keyword().onField("firstName").matching("abraham").createQuery())
                .should(qb.keyword().onField("lastName").matching("lincoln").createQuery())
                .should(qb.keyword().onField("phone").matching("9895873039").createQuery())
                .should(qb.keyword().onField("email").matching("abraham@gmail.com").createQuery()).createQuery();



    FullTextQuery query = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Notes.class);
            query.setProjection(
                FullTextQuery.SCORE,
                FullTextQuery.EXPLANATION,
                FullTextQuery.THIS);


    List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();

    for(Object[] a : results)
    {

        ObjectMapper om=new ObjectMapper();

        Object[] firstResult = (Object[]) a;
        String score = firstResult[0].toString();
        String explanation = firstResult[1].toString();
        Patients o = (Patients) firstResult[2];

        log.debug("score query : " + score);
        log.debug("explanation query : " + explanation);
        log.debug("o query : " + om.writeValueAsString(o));
    }
```

what i need is, score as 4 for objects which match all fields

score as 3 for objects which match any 3 fields

score as 2 for objects which match any 2 fields

score as 1 for objects which match any 1 field

is this possible??

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: How??? do you have any example

Comment: There is a "withConstantScore()" function for should queries

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to rethink your requirements and see if your really need this "score". If what you want is to order the documents from the "most matching" to the "least matching", then Hibernate Search (Lucene, actually) already does that by default.

Now, if you really need this "score"... The easiest way is probably to run multiple queries:

- the first one will be your query, as is
- the second one will be a query on the "firstName" field only, and an additional filter on IDs to only consider the entities that matched the first query
- the third one will be a query on the "lastName" field only, and an additional filter on IDs to only consider the entities that matched the first query
- the fourth one will be a query on the "phone" field only, and an additional filter on IDs to only consider the entities that matched the first query
- the fifth one will be a query on the "email" field only, and an additional filter on IDs to only consider the entities that matched the first query

Then you can compute, for each result of the first query, how many of the other queries matched it. This will give you your "score".

Obviously performance will not be great, since you will be running five queries instead of one. But at least it should do what you want.

If you want better performance and are not afraid of difficulty... There might be a way to compute the number of matched fields and use that as a score by creating your own Lucene Query implementation, instead of using the default BooleanQuery (that's what the Hibernate Search query builder does). But I wouldn't recommend that unless you have advanced knowledge of Lucene: working with Lucene internals is really not easy. Also, by doing that you would lose the ability to sort your results by Lucene's default score, which is far more subtle.

If you want to go this way, have a look at the source code of `org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery`, `org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanWeight` and `org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanScorer`. Depending on the licensing terms of your projects, you might be able to copy/paste this code, rename the classes and alter the code to fit your needs. Once again, I **do not recommend** that.

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48558309/6692043

Comment: okay, if i follow multiple query approach, how i will get matching entities for 3 fields???

Comment: The string generated by projection of EXPLANATION will actually include all the parts before being combined in the final score. If you don't like to run multiple queries, you could use that.

Comment: @Shafeef Batry: Use "must" query for the 3 fields, then you only get values where every field matches